# How to update/PUT an object property with a new model/chid Webflux Spring Reactive

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have model (**Hospital**) that has a property of of (**Procedure**). When I first create the Hospital with a POST that's just the name, contact, etc. I then wanted to update the Procedure property in a different PUT request.

I've tried calling the setProcedure setter but when I do I keep getting this in my Procedures property for the Hospital Object,

```
"procedure": {
  "scanAvailable": true, 
  "prefetch": -1
}

// it should be like so i.e example
"procedure": {
  "name": "xray", 
  "price": 1.0,
  "hosp_id": 111..,
  "id" : 222...
}
```

I first create(POST) create the hospital, after I would update(PUT) by pushing or setting the Flux of procedures int the procedure property.

```
{
    "name": "Mercy Hospital",
    "address": "3663 S Miami Ave",
    "phone": "305-854-4400",
    "zipcode": "33133",
    "city": "Miami",
    "state": "FL",
    "lat": 25.7400049,
    "lng": -80.21352600000002,
    "procedure": {
        "scanAvailable": true, <---- the response i'm getting
        "prefetch": -1
    },
    "id": "5d539346e440ed05dfd0fe8a"
}
```

**Like I mentioned I created two models with a constructor and getters and setters for each.**

**Hospital**

```java
@Document // Identifies this class as domain object to be persisted to mongodb
public class Hospital {


    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String zipcode;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private List<Procedure> procedure;

    @Id
    private String id;

    //
    public Hospital() {
    }

    public Hospital(String name, String address, String phone, String zipcode, String city, String state, double lat, double lng) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.lat = lng;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

// All the Getters and Setters
```

**Procedure**

```java
@Document
public class Procedure {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String hosp_id;
    @Id
    private String id;

    public Procedure() {
    }

    public Procedure(String name, double price, String hosp_id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.hosp_id = hosp_id;
    }

    // all the Getters and setters Here

}
```

**Controller :**

```java
@RestController // Controller and ResponseBody Annotations together
@RequestMapping("/hospitals/v1/hosp/") // Create a base string that the endpoint is built upon
@CrossOrigin // For DEV Angular and Spring app locally REMOVE FOR PRODUCTION
public class HospitalController {
     private final HospitalService hospitalService;

    @Autowired
    public HospitalController(HospitalService hospitalService) {
        this.hospitalService = hospitalService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "{id}", produces = 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Mono<Hospital> getHospital(@PathVariable String id) {
       return hospitalService.getHospital(id);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "{hosp_id}/services", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Mono<Hospital> createService(@RequestBody List<Procedure> procedureMono, @PathVariable String hosp_id) {
      return hospitalService.createService(procedureMono, hosp_id);
    }
```

**Service**

```java
public Mono<Hospital> getHospital(String id) {
    return reactiveMongoOperations.findById(id, Hospital.class);
}

public Mono<Hospital> createService(List<Procedure> procedureMono, String hosp_id) {
    return getHospital(hosp_id).doOnNext(hospital -> hospital.setProcedure(procedureMono));
}
```

Comment: _"I've tried setting the Procedure property but keep getting in my Procedures property"_ -- Sorry, but this is not a meaningful English sentence.  Please explain more clearly what problem you are having, and what you have done to troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks for catching that, I fixed the grammer and problem

Comment: if you have solved the problem, you can write an answer for it too. It would be useful to others.

Comment: sorry but i meant the description of the problem, still trying to get this to work

Comment: Are you sure you've imported the correct `Procedure` in your `Hospital` class?

Comment: Yea I just double checked it is,

Comment: please post your full controller class, where does Flux<Procedure> come from.

Answer (score 1):

You get this because you are trying to serialize/deserialize a `Flux` or a `Mono`.

you can't return a

```
public class Hospital {
    private Flux<Procedure> procedure;
}
```

You can only serialize/deserialize concrete types

```
public class Hospital {
    private List<Procedure> procedure;
}
```

Since you have not posted your full controller i can not understand fully what it is you want to do, but you can't serialize/deserialize Monos or Fluxes.

Comment: I updated my code above with controller and Service, i'll look into serialize/deserialize